# How to open VS Code and pass commands to integrated termianal via CLI

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wonder how to use the `code` command to open the **VS Code** with the **[integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)** launching within with some commands running that I pass directly to the integrated terminal.

Right now I need to do a couple of actions to get it done:

1. open VS Code via `code .`
2. manually open the *built-in* terminal and run a command like `npm run start`

Maybe it's possible to open VS Code like this: `code . --exec 'npm run start'`, and it may open the editor and also run another command in the integrated terminal just after VS Code is ready for work.

I look through the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) and I couldn't find anything useful for this case. Maybe I need to look for something like plugin or tricky bash/zsh script?

*Reminder: it’s important to run these “passed” commands via CLI directly in the integrated (built-in) terminal of the newly opened VS Code instance. I know that it's possible to open the editor and **then** run commands, like `code . && npm run start`, but it will be just another command in sequence after `code`, it's not the same as running commands in integrated terminal.*

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this GitHub's issue will help https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7266

Comment: NinjaDeveloper, well, they are discussing the ability to open the shell with arguments in vs code, not the command that runs vs code with arguments that being executed in the built-in terminal after it's ready, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Maybe look into the extension API. There's APIs to create terminals and send text to them, and you could have a custom CLI command that writes the command to run into a file for the extension to read before starting VSCode.