# Windows .bat Scripting: Open VSCODE and run npm start within the terminal

Tags: windows, batch-file, npm

i want to create a Windows shell script that opens vscode in a given directory and executes 'npm start' **within** vs code. Is that possible? I am facing some problems, hopefully you can help me.

**My Script**

---

```
@echo off
set codePath=C:\Users\repo\source\
set currrentWorkingDirectory=%cd%
set VSCODE="C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe"



call:start_service_ui

GOTO :EOF
:start_service_ui
echo start service UI ...
set service_ui_path=%codePat%project1\service-ui


call %VSCODE% %service_ui_path%

npm start
ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF
```

**1. Problem**

---

When I call *%VSCODE% %service_ui_path%*, VSCode is opening but i can see the log information there, so the terminal is blocked by the VSCode operations - how can I stop that?
The same counts for *npm start*

**2. Problem**

---

I want to call the *npm start* command within VSCode, but I want to determine this in the .bat file.
Is there any possiblity to do so? I coulnd´t find anything online about that.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `npm start` to `call npm start` since `npm` is a batch file on its own; without `call`, execution never returns to your batch file…

Comment: You have a spelling error in this line of code. `set service_ui_path=%codePat%project1\service-ui`

Comment: The question has been [asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57430539), but was unresolved